# SetColumn, SetRow, SetColumnSpan are not working for me in UWP

Tags: uwp, grid

I'm trying to dynamically assign Elements for my GRID in XAML with the use of Objects. However the method in Grid that allows to SetRows or Column does not work.

The code is as followed:

[image]

The error i receive is as followed:

[image]

I see a lot of users here that can use that method without any isues. So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Any updates for this thread?

Answer (score 1):

You can not set the Row or Column of a Grid by using SetColumn or SetRow you have to do it like this:

```
_grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
_grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = GridLength.Auto });
_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });
_grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = GridLength.Auto });

//Similar to xaml:
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefintion height = "*"/>
    ...
```

And this is the way, you can use to set the Grid row and column for the children in the Grid.

```
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock1, 0);
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock2, 1);
Grid.SetRow(textBlock3, 0);
Grid.SetRow(textBlock4, 1);

//Similar to xaml:
<TextBlock Grid.Column="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> SetColumn, SetRow, SetColumnSpan are not working for me in UWP

Please refer to Grid [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid.setcolumn?view=winrt-22621) `SetColumn, SetRow, SetColumnSpan` are static method, so you can not use *grid instance* to call such method. if want to update element's positon where in the [Grid container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid?view=winrt-22621#examples), you just call above method with Grid calss name.

```
_grid.ChildRen.Add(textBlock);
Grid.SetColumn(textBlock, 0);
Grid.SetRow(textBlock, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(textBlock, 0);
```